# How to implement lambda function inside the class?

Tags: python

How to implement lambda function within a class? Here is my code doing exactly what I want it to do with a square function but I want to see if it's possible to replace the square function with a lambda function.

```
class Cal:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num=num

    #squares = lambda num: num * 2

    def squares(self):
        return self.num*2

for i in range(11):
    s1=Cal(i)
    print(s1.squares())
```

```
class Cal:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num=num
    #squares = lambda num: num * 2
    def squares(self):
        return self.num*2

for i in range(11):
    s1=Cal(i)
    print(s1.squares(), end=' , ')
```

Comment: Thats really not what lambdas are made for... You should use a normal function.

Comment: side note, use `**2` to square.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
class Cal:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num=num
Cal.squares = lambda cal: cal.num * 2

for i in range(11):
    s1=Cal(i)
    print(s1.squares(), end=' , ')
```

but there is no point in doing this

Answer (score 0):

You can, this will work fine for you:

```
class Cal:

    def __init__(self, num):
       self.num = num

    squares = lambda self: self.num * 2

for i in range(11):
     s1 = Cal(i)
     print(s1.squares())
```

**BUT** you shouldn't do this as lambdas are not meant to be used in this way. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/890188/11131433) wich show how lambdas are typically used.